# AutoMapper sets Date to Null instead of Ignoring

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I am trying to map an entityModel to an entity while keeping one of the destination entity's field value.

I have the following classes in .NET:

```
class Entity {
 public string User {get; set;}
 public DateTime Date {get; set;}
}

class EntityModel {
 public string User {get; set;}
 public DateTime Date {get; set;}
}
```

And the following Mapper configuration made

```
CreateMap<EntityModel, Entity>()
 .ForMember(f => f.Date, m => m.Ignore());
```

I want to be able to do `mapper.Map<EntityModel, Entity>(entityModel, entity)` so that it copies the User string over the entity but keeps the original destination entity's Date. However what happens is that the destination entity's Date becomes DateTime.MinValue (01/01/0001 00:00:00).

I am using the latest AutoMapper (12.0.1)

EDIT: Managed to reproduce the problem! It seems like it happens when there's a list involved:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ud3co4

As you can see here the date of ChildEntity[0] changes after the mapping

Comment: Could you please add a bit more code so that you have a [mcve]? Something anyone could copy/paste and it will run (after installing the nuget package). Thank you.

Comment: Wait: does this mean you have an entity and just "update" it by a DTO (excluding the Date property)?

Comment: Yes, precisely @Fildor,

I'm working on that right now Igor, sorry

Comment: Well seems like I can't reproduce the issue outside of the project itself

https://dotnetfiddle.net/bfc3g0

This works fine. In my environment though parentEntity.ChildEntity.Date would be DateTime.MinValue after the mapping.

Comment: Then there must be a difference. Did you "dumb down" your models and entities for example sake? If so, maybe step by step make them more and more similar to the original until you start to see the observed behavior.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods I've updated the original post with the dotnetfiddle link where I've finally been able to reproduce the behaviour. It seems like it has to do with the nested List of Entity

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: Now, that's something to work with. But I am afraid, you'll need to put in some manual effort, there.